# Self contained .net core web app

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .net core web app that I would like to install as a regular app on Windows or OSX. If I deploy that as a self contained app, will the web server start when the .exe is run? And, how can I configure what port the app will listen on?

My long term goal would be to create a UI to let the user configure some stuff and have the app distributable from Windows Store and/or Mac AppStore, but I'm not sure if this is possible?

Comment: Look into [Kestrel. Configuring Listening Address](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-core/2262/publishing-and-deployment/7433/kestrel-configuring-listening-address#t=201706260521401456357) for port configuring

Answer (score 2):

In order to deply as a self contained app you need to specify a runtime in your csproj file.
:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Than publish the application for that runtime:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
```

If you want to change the port your application is listening on you need to set that in the Program.cs file:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            // Set url and port here.
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5005")
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

You can now run your app by running the yourapp.exe file in your publish directiry.